# Java : my loop never ends and is there a smarter way too code it

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

the idea is that if for example they choose * if will say wrong operator please try again but at the moment that is just looping if I choose the wrong operator and also if I choose the right operator the program needs to end , I cant seem to figure it out

my code is as follows

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


   public class Uppgift5 {
public static void main (String[] args){

    int tal1, tal2;
    int sum = 0;
    int sub=0;
    String operator;


    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("write in first digit");
    tal1 = input.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Write in 2nd digit ");
    tal2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter + to add and - subtract ");
    operator = input2.nextLine();


    while (operator.equals("-") || operator.equals("+")|| operator.equals("*")  || operator.equals(("/")) ){

    if (operator.equals("+")){
        sum = tal1+tal2;
        System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);
    }

    else if (operator.equals("-")){
        sub = tal1-tal2;
        System.out.println("the subtracted value  is " + sub);

    }
    if (operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("/")){ 
    System.out.println("You have put in the wrong operator, your options are + or -");
}

}
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
operator = input2.nextLine();
while (operator.equals("-") || operator.equals("+")|| operator.equals("*")  || operator.equals(("/")) )
```

Assume `operator` is `+`. The value of `operator` does not change within the `while` loop, so `operator` will always be `+`, and you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator will never be different. For that reason, your loops never end. You should use **if** instead of **while**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `while` loop, use a [`do` loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#do_..._while_loop) that starts before you read `operator` from the input and only loops back if `operator` is not `+` or `-`.  Ideally the `while` at the end of the `do` loop should come before you attempt the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course your code never ends... because you have no stopping condition. Also, your looping condition is incorrect. As long as the operator is one of those values, the loop will run. Also, you never ask for an input inside the loop. The code below should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class tt {
public static void main (String[] args){

int tal1, tal2;
int sum = 0;
int sub=0;
String operator = "";


Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("write in first digit");
tal1 = input.nextInt();


System.out.println("Write in 2nd digit ");
tal2 = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter + to add and - subtract ");

while (true){

operator = input2.nextLine();
if (operator.equals("+")){
    sum = tal1+tal2;
    System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);
}
else if (operator.equals("-")){
    sub = tal1-tal2;
    System.out.println("the subtracted value  is " + sub);

}

if (operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("/")){
    System.out.println("You have put in the wrong operator, your options are + or -");
    break;
  }
  }
 }
}
```